# Best way of adding additional values to form get url

Tags: forms, codeigniter, url

I was wondering, which is the best way to add additional values to an url created by a form with a GET method... the url looks something like

`http://testing.com/results?search_query=landscape&search_filter[]=mountain`

I'll have on the results page additional filters and paging system, and I was wondering which is the best way of adding the values of those once chosen/selected **to the url**? So if clicked on next button it will add a `&page=X` to the url or/and a `&sort_by=top_rate`

Answer (score 0):

You can use checkboxes:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="search_filter[]" value="mountain" />
<input type="checkbox" name="search_filter[]" value="landscape" />
```

or multiselect:

```html
<select multiple="multiple" name="search_filter[]">
  <option value="landscape">Landscape</option>
  <option value="mountain">Mountain</option>
</select>
```

Comment: check the edit, it's not the forms I am worried about... it's how to add their values to the url

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I get the question, but I think the location object may be of help.

Try location.href and then changing it. The browser will change to that new url. So you could get the current, then add your stuff, setting that appended version back into location.href. I think this is what you want, as long as you want the user's browser to navigate to that page.

There is a modern method that allows you to just modify the address bar and title without refreshing/navigating away, using window.history.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/history.html#history-0

Specifically you might be interested in window.history.pushState. This will let their back buttons work too. :)

Hope this was more along the lines you were looking for!

Answer (score -2):

You need to read your URL in the action script.

Check if the URL has any parameter.

If the URL has some parameters, then append at the end: &newPARAM=newVALUE (you can add as many as you wish).

If the URL has no parameters, then append to the end: ?newPARAM=newValue

Comment: that's exactly what I am asking... the best way of adding those new values... not how to work with them. But thanks any way